# How do I set my windows machine up to recieve incoming faxes?

Tags: fax

Is there a way I can configure my windows computers to answer the phone using the built in modem and then print out what it receives automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are instructions for:

- [Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306550)
- [Windows Vista](http://windowshelp.microsoft.com/Windows/en-US/help/488ac4fb-7436-4a03-bb70-6ded839dd3c21033.mspx)